# html5 picture tag is not working responsive with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set different pictures with the html5 `<picture>` tag. I set the 2 pictures inside a bootstrap grid, so the picture is responsive until the breakpoint `768px`, where the picture change.

When I minimize the browser screensize, I can see the picture is not responsive. How can that be? The bootstrap code should be correct?

[A demo can be seen here](http://zalis.dk/testing.html).

The html code is not looking good in the code snippet. Therefore I post it here to:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
            <picture>
                <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg">
                <source media="(min-width: 380px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/380.jpg">
                <img src="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg" alt=“test” style="width:auto;">
            </picture>
            <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
                <h3>Here is headline 1</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    /* Set width between grid elements */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:10px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:5px;
    }
    .margin_bottom {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .row {
      margin-left: -5px;
      margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .img-responsive { 
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Position of buttons/text in a single grid element */
    .inner-wrapper {
      text-align: center;
      background: none;
    }
    .centered {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .bottom-right {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 16px;
    }

    .bottom-left {
        position: absolute;

        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
    }
    /* Color on text */
    .dark-font {
      color: #333;
    }
    .light-font {
      color: #fff;
    }
   
    /* Set full width on columns */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .img-responsive { /*EDIT*/
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        }
      .btn-success {
        width: fit-content;
      }
      /* Here you go */
      .height-m {
        height: 350px;
      }

    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
      h3 {
        font-size: 1.2em;

      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
           <picture>
                <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg">
                <source media="(min-width: 380px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/380.jpg">
                <img src="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg" alt=“test” style="width:auto;">
            </picture>
            <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
                <h3>Here is headline 1</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you've presented seems to be working fine ( https://www.bootply.com/fqGVgpbC54 ). Have you ensured that you're viewing this in a browser that supports picture and source media declarations?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The picture is changing fine. But when minimizing the screen from fx 1200px - 800 px, the picture is not reizing. The picture should follow the size of the screen.

Comment: Try setting the width of the image to `100%` instead of `auto`. That looks better and responsive.

Comment: Cool, that seems to do the job. Thanks. Please lay an answer, so I can close the question

Comment: Glad I could help. Posted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `boostrap` template you're using is indeed correct and does provide some sort of responsiveness, but the `image` has no specified `width`. The browser therefore won't scale it.

Setting a `width` relative to its parent should fix it, e.g.

```
width: 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the image width to `100%` instead of `auto` should make it responsive.